# Access status response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With `AngularJS` i am unable to access the http status in the error callback, as it skips right to the last else block.

**What am i doing wrong, and how am i supposed to do it correctly?**

```
UserService.login($scope.credentials).$promise.then(
                // success callback
                function (data) {
                    var chars = CharacterService.getUser({name: data.username});
                    $rootScope.user = User.build(data, chars);

                    $timeout(function () {
                        $state.go('sheet');
                    });
                },
                // error callback
                function (data, status) {
                    if (status == 404) {
                        $scope.invalidUser = true;
                        $scope.credentials = {};
                    }
                    else if (status == 401) {
                        $scope.invalidPass = true;
                        $scope.credentials = {};
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(status);
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the status is coming back as?

Comment: It alerts the json object being returned as [Object object], also the status code returned is 404 with incorrect username, and 401 with incorrect password. Which is supposed to happen. - so it does take the (data) part, but not the (status) part. The data part isn't even needed anyway, just adds confusion :-p i'll remove it.

Comment: is `status` a field in your JSON data object or the "real" status of the request ?

Comment: That would be the actual http status, not a field in the object. - This used to work when i used $http.

Comment: Updated the final else block to alert only (status), it is undefined when it alerts.

Comment: I think only data should be populated, according to the documentation I see only one argument should be stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've figured out your problem. What you wrote would have worked if you didn't use `.then()`, which returns a new promise.

If you used `.success` and `.error` your code would work.

In your case, all the values you need are in the first `data` argument, so you just need to change to:

```
function (data) {
        if (data.status == 404) {
             $scope.invalidUser = true;
             $scope.credentials = {};
        }
        else if (data.status == 401) {
             $scope.invalidPass = true;
             $scope.credentials = {};
        }
        else {
           alert(data.status);
        }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cAMc6/82/)